# Long Polling in Django- Return the response when there occurs an activity in the DB

Tags: jquery, python, django, long-polling

I've read on SO regarding Long Polling in Django, but my problem is not a complex one which requires using tornado or building a chat application.

I've a JS client, which send a polling request after N seconds. I need to update the table containing information from the DB. I poll request the server and if there is any activity on the specific table in the DB, then that row(s) should be fetched and returned to the client.

Lets say my models is

```
class ABC(models.Model):
    field1 = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    field2 = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    field3 = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
```

If there is any activity happening on model `ABC`, it should alert me and should be send back to the client with its info.

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
function addmsg_to_table(msg){
    //apending to div
}

function waitForMsg(){
    /* This requests the url "msgsrv.php"
    When it complete (or errors)*/
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "msgsrv.php",

        async: true, /* If set to non-async, browser shows page as "Loading.."*/
        cache: false,
        timeout:50000, /* Timeout in ms */

        success: function(data){ 
            addmsg_to_table(data); 
            setTimeout(
                waitForMsg, /* Request next message */
                1000 /* ..after 1 seconds */
            );
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
            addmsg_to_table(textStatus + " (" + errorThrown + ")");
            setTimeout(
                waitForMsg, /* Try again after.. */
                15000); /* milliseconds (15seconds) */
        }
    });
};

$(document).ready(function(){
    waitForMsg(); /* Start the inital request */
});
</script>
```

How can I do it ? How should i model my views.py to send the response. **How do I get to know whether an activity has occurred on a table or not?** I'm completely new to it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are two ways to solve this problem, which stem from the fact that there is no sane way to use Django as a real-time framework.

To properly do real-time notifications you'll have to deploy a real-time server, such as Tornado. The flow will work such that whenever an object is saved you announce it to some messaging/queuing backend. Tornado on the other side will listen to such events and then distribute them to the relevant clients via WebSockets (or an abstraction layer like Sock.JS).

If this is a low-traffic scenario, and if deploying Tornado is absolutely out of the question you're left with long polling once every `N` seconds. The query itself can be either be executed on a `last_updated` field that you can add to the model.

Alternatively, you can try a sophisticated solution that ignores the database entirely, and utilizes the cache to return a quick result if a specific record was recently updated. But this really depends on your models and usage patterns.

Comment: Well, my application is not that BIG to use tornado or web sockets(as previously mentioned). for me Polling after every N seconds suits best. But my actual query was How will I get to know whether an activity has occurred in my table within that N seconds range, IF I dont have the time field in my model. Had I been having a `time` field in my models, I would've easily got the result list within the range, but since I dont have the time field, how will I get to know whether an activity has happened on my table or not?

Answer (score 0):

I recently had to get an update notification from a table and found that PostgreSQL provides a Listen/Notify channel feature which worked for me. When a function tries to modify the table, use a Notify to send the notification to the channel. Any client listening to the channel will receive the Notify event and you can perform the operation you'd like.
This is the Github link that helped me understand the usage of it in Python -

[Listen/Notify PostgreSQL feature](https://gist.github.com/kissgyorgy/beccba1291de962702ea9c237a900c79)

Do not forget to include the conn.set_isolation_level line.